# Docusign Void Envelope Message

Tags: docusignapi

How do I edit or set the message that gets sent when I use the MoveEnvelope API endpoint to void an envelope.  The email that is sent to the signer has a message saying that is been voided for the following reason

"Moved to recycle bin via API method MoveEnvelopes"

How do I change this message? 
Here is a link to the API I am using
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/moveEnvelopes/

Comment: Hi. A bit more detail would help you reach appropriate helpers. For example, what language are you using? Maybe add a tag for that. Also, as far as I can tell (as a total foreigner for docusign) a quick look at reference says there is no `moveFolder` API, so you might want to edit.

Comment: I am using PHP on a LAMP stack.  Here is the link to the docusign API that I am using.  It's called MoveEnvelopes not movefolder. 
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/moveEnvelopes/

Answer (score 1):

I found that the envelopes API will allow me to void an envelope and set the void reason 
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Void%20Envelope.htmT

However it doesn't move the envelope to the recycle bin. So I am making two API calls. One to void it and another to move it.

Comment: the link is broken